# Pass multiple arguments to a Func<> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

This is from a programming test, so I'm sure that there is better way to do this, but the question required this specific answer.

I've a method Result which simply matches a predicate and returns a bool, and the predicate in question checks an array of strings to report if any string exceeds length 5.

```
static bool Result<T>(T[] values, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (values.Where<T>(predicate).Count() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

static bool StringLengthLessThan5(string str)
{
    return str.Length < 5;
}
```

Finally this is used like this -

```
bool val2 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, StringLengthLessThan5);
```

This works as expected, however now I need to use the same kind of code but parametrize the Func to allow a dynamic value for the string length, i.e my `Func<string,bool>` now needs to be `Func<string,int,bool>`

```
static bool StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(string str,int length)
{
    return str.Length < length;
}
```

or alternately,

```
static Func<string, int, bool> FuncForDynamicStringlength = (s, i) => s.Length < i;
```

My question is this, in the spirit of keeping the calling code for the new Func the same, i.e. I still want to use -

```
Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber);
```

but, how do I pass the parameters?

The Func now expects 2 parameters, the first being a string and the second being the int, how do I pass the first parameter? I can pass the int length to compare, but I'm stumped on the first parameter.

I realize that I can loop through my string[] and call the Func in a foreach like this (I know that this makes no sense in this specific instance since I'm overwriting the value of a bool, but I'm sure you get my question) -

```
foreach(string str in new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" })
{
    bool val3_1 = StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(str, 5);
}
```

but I would like to use my original code, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the predicate into lambda expression and pass in desired length using variable or constant like so:

```
int len = 5;
bool val1 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, x => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(x, len));
bool val2 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, x => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(x, 5));
```

Another way of solving this, would be defining extension method for `string` collections.

```
public static class StringCollectionExtensions
{
    public static bool HasLengthLessThan(this IEnumerable<string> collection, int length)
    {
        return collection.Any(x => x.Length < length);
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
var testStrings = new string[5] {"asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv"};

bool val3 = testStrings.HasLengthLessThan(6);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the use of Extension methods, but like I was telling Ed, I'm more interested in your first post - 
bool val2 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, x => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(x, 5));
with - 
 static bool StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(string str,int length)
        {
            return str.Length < length;
        }
However, I get a compilation error that Delegate Func does not take 1 argument. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @rakesh Just tried and it compiles just fine. There is something else wrong with your code. You can see it in action here: http://rextester.com/CTPBX83730 Just click Run button on the bottom.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, I was using the Func with 2 input parameters, your code does compile fine.

Comment: Your code lead to another question, I'll ask here if that is okay.
I modified your code - http://rextester.com/edit/XAWWQS51026, 
and I do not understand how the Func<T, bool> predicate is being satisfied by
static bool StringLengthGreaterThanGivenNumber(string str, int length, int length2, int length3).

There clearly is a mismatch on the number of parameters.

Comment: Because it is wrapped in lambda that itself is Func <string, bool>. And that lambda calls the other method passing in all the required arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You could also look into [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). You can write another function that takes in a function with `n` parameters and returns you a function that takes in `n-1` parameters. Internally, the new function maintains a reference to some piece of data that is known at call time. For example:

```
static Func<string, bool> PartialApply(Func<string, int, bool> action, int length)
{
    return (string str) => action(str, length);
}
```

Here, you define a function that takes in a `Func` with two parameters and a boolean return type. You will use this function create a new function that only takes in one parameter:

```
var stringLessThan6 = PartialApply(StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber, 6);
```

Now, you're using a variable to refer to the new function rather than writing (and naming) a new function in your class. You generate this new function on-the-fly. This allows you to create different variations just by altering the parameter:

```
var stringLessThan1 = PartialApply(StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber, 1);
var stringLessThan10 = PartialApply(StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber, 10);
var stringLessThan1000 = PartialApply(StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber, 1000);
```

Since you now have functions that only take in a `string` and return a `bool`, you can use those where your predicates are expected:

```
bool val2 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, stringLessThan6);
bool val2 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, stringLessThan10);
bool val3 = Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, stringLessThan1000);
```

Comment: Interesting, never heard of PartialApply, let me do some reading.

Comment: I did some reading and I cannot thank you enough. I've a new tool in my toolbox and I wish I could mark all of these solutions as the answer and even though I couldn't mark yours, please know that you have my gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you actually want:

```
var result4 = strings.Any(s => s.Length < 6);
```

No new method needed. But what you're doing is a worthwhile exercise.

So here's the exact answer to your question, with a few additions.

1. Never require a parameter to be an array unless there's some particular reason your method *needs* it to be an array. This one doesn't. `IEnumerable<T>` is all we need, so we just accept that. An array of `string` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, so we can accept an array.
2. `Count()` may require going through the whole sequence, depending on what was passed in. No need to do that if all you're asking is whether it's zero or not. `Any()` stops and returns `true` the first time the predicate finds a match. It's also simpler, and the name says what it's doing. It's not like `s.Where(p).Count() > 0` is all *that* harder to read than `s.Any(p)`, but in a large code base, every little bit counts.
3. Let's make it an extension method too. They're handy, they're expected since what we're doing here is Linq, and you can still use it as a regular method instead, i.e. `f(a, n, p)` and `a.f(n, p)` are both fine with the compiler.

OK:

```
static bool Result<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> values, T2 param, Func<T1, T2, bool> predicate)
{
    return values.Any(t1 => predicate(t1, param));
}

static bool StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(string str, int len)
{
    return str.Length < len;
}
```

Thus:

```
var strings = new string[] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv", "planxty" };
var result = strings.Result(6, StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber);
```

That works, but it's inflexible. There are cases where it might make sense: Filtering based on user input in a form, maybe. The predicate comes from one selection, and the parameter comes from somewhere else.

In general, though, you'd be better off passing the `param` as part of the predicate, much the way you originally had it. See Kenneth K's excellent answer for a classic way to clean up this approach, which I should have remembered.

```
static bool Result2<T1>(this IEnumerable<T1> values, Func<T1, bool> predicate)
{
    return values.Any(predicate);
}
```

...

```
var result2 = strings.Result2(s => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(s, 6));
```

Or better yet:

```
var result3 = strings.Result2(s => s.Length < 6);
```

Comment: I was just going to ask you about these being extension methods and I think I know how to solve this using an extension method, but I would still like to know if I could just use - Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber); in some form with the right set of parameters

Comment: `LengthLessThan`extension method would be even cleaner :)

Comment: @KasparsOzols Yes! Add it to your answer!

Comment: @Rakesh You have to pass in "given number" somehow. I gave you two ways to do that.

Comment: @Ed - So what I'm trying to do is not directly possible, other than using Extension methods or doing a foreach and passing the strings individually.

Comment: @Rakesh Extension methods have nothing to do with the parameter. I have no idea what you're talking about with the "foreach". There's no foreach here, and there shouldn't be. What you are trying to do is very simple. I showed you how to do it. Kenneth K showed you how to do it. Kaspars showed you how to do it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - yes, I understand Extension methods to some extent and what I can gather from your comments is that what I initially set out to do is not possible when I have an extra int parameter - please tell me if this is correct.
I understand that there are other ways to get to what I'm trying to do and I know a few and you (and others) have enlightened me on many more, but I'm just trying to understand the limitations on the approach in the question from the test.

Comment: @Rakesh At least one of us does not understand anything the other  is saying. I don't know which. Maybe both.

Comment: @Rakesh If there's an extra parameter, you must somehow pass it. How can it be there if it comes from nowhere? If you want to compare some number to another number, you must have both numbers to compare them. You can't compare `a` to `b` if you only have `a`. You must also have `b`. Somebody must specify a value for `b`. If it is a constant, that's easy. If it is not a constant, somebody must provide a value for it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I'm sorry if I aapear thick, I totally understand what you are saying and the fact that we need to pass the other parameter.
My question simply was - Can I do this
Result(new string[5] { "asdf", "a", "asdsffsfs", "wewretete", "adcv" }, StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber (param1,5));
May be this is not possible, I just wanted to ask.

Comment: @Rakesh I apologize if I sounded like I'm saying that -- that wasn't my intent.

Comment: @Rakesh My last example looks very close to what you describe: `strings.Result2(s => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(s, 6));`. Note that the same method could be called like this as well: `Result2(strings, s => StringLengthLessThanGivenNumber(s, 6));` -- the compiler is happy either way.